# probability for cards

Tags: probability

I pick 5 cards uniformly at random from a deck of 52 cards (13 different values for 4 different suits). I tell you that the first card I drew was a 4 of hearts. What is the probability that my hand contains 4 of a kind? (Four cards of the same value in different suits.)

Comment: Any thoughts?  Hint:  handle the cases "four $4's$" and "four non-$4's$" separately.

Comment: Alternate hint:  does it matter which card you draw first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases:

If you obtained $3$ other $4$'s in your hand, then the probability that this could have happened is $\frac{\binom{4}{3}\cdot48}{\binom{51}{4}}$, since there are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways of choosing the $3$ cards and there are $48$ other cards in the deck.

If you obtained a $4$-of-a-kind in another rank, the probability is $\frac{12}{\binom{51}{4}}$, since there are $12$ other ranks to choose from.

Therefore, the answer is $\frac{\binom{4}{3}\cdot48+12}{\binom{51}{4}}=\frac{1}{1225}$.

Comment: Rather than just telling the whole answer, you should leave it at telling how to get the answer.  Let the student do some work on their own.

Comment: i think this not true, why to obtains 3 other 4's in the hand is 4 choose 3?